# Recursion in instance method in python

Tags: python, recursion, tree, tree-structure

I am trying to define a recursive method to walk all the nodes of a tree. I defined the Tree as the following:

```
class Tree(object):

    def __init__(self, value, lson=None, sibling=None):
        self.value = value
        if lson:
            self.lson = Tree(lson)
        else: 
            self.lson = None

        if sibling:
            self.sibling = Tree(sibling)
        else:
            self.sibling = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```

I have the following function that works:

```
def walk_tree(t):
    # walk in order
    print t
    if t.lson:
        walk_tree(t.lson)
    if t.sibling:
        walk_tree(t.sibling)
    return t
```

How do I turn this to an instance method?

```
def walk_tree(self):
    # walk in order
    print self.value
    if self.lson:
        self.walk_tree(self.lson)
    if self.sibling:
        self.walk_tree(self.sibling)
    return self
```

This will result in `Max recursion depth error...`

a. Is this how do you implement a recursive method?
 b. Is there a justification here to use `yield`?
 c. Is there a justification here to use `@staticmethod` which recieves a `Tree` instance?

Comment: It only works if you still have a global `walk_tree()`.

Comment: darn you are right, I was wondering that it works. In earlier versions, I saw `File "trees1.py", line 59, in walk_tree
    self.walk_tree()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive method is not recursive. It calls a *global* `walk_tree()` that may or may not be recursive itself.

To make a method properly recursive, reference the method *on the sub-nodes*:

```
def walk_tree(self):
    # walk in order
    print self.value
    if self.lson:
        self.lson.walk_tree()
    if self.sibling:
        self.sibling.walk_tree()
    return self
```

This only ever *prints* values, it doesn't return anything but the top-level node to the initial caller.

`yield` can help give access to the values efficiently, but you do need to remember to yield recursive calls:

```
def walk_tree(self):
    # walk in order
    yield self.value
    if self.lson:
        for res in self.lson.walk_tree():
            yield res
    if self.sibling:
        for res in self.sibling.walk_tree():
            yield res
```

or, using Python 3.3 or up, with `yield from` generator delegation:

```
def walk_tree(self):
    # walk in order
    yield self.value
    if self.lson:
        yield from self.lson.walk_tree()
    if self.sibling:
        yield from self.sibling.walk_tree()
```

A static method is just a namespaced function; your original `walk_tree()` global could be made into a static method, sure, but there is little point unless you feel the namespace clarifies your API.

Comment: @Oz123: Actually, it should have given you an exception about having an argument too many; I've corrected it to delegate to the child nodes.

Comment: Thank you! This was the missing piece. Now I have a problem with your `walk_tree` with `yield`. It runs, but finishes with an error: `TypeError: 'Tree' object is not iterable`. I could probably wrap it with `Try ... Except`, it just feels weired.

Comment: @Oz123: then `self.lson.walk_tree()` or `self.sibling.walk_tree()` is not a generator but returns a `Tree` object. Make sure these are all the same type or at least implement `walk_tree()` the same way; as a generator.

Comment: Ok, now everything works. The function, instance method, and instance method with generator. Thanks for that.